# Probability of getting non-negative real number n-tuple (which sum=S) in which every variable is not greater than S/2

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

n non-negative real numbers choosen such that their sum=S . What is probability of getting n-tuple such that every number of tuple is less than or equal to S/2?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843105/probability-with-infinite-sample-space#comment5863289_2843105

Comment: above mentioned link question is case of integer and what I ask is case of real numbers

Comment: Fair (I linked it in case some answer here may shed light there, or vice-versa). What have you tried, however, to tackle your own question? For instance, can you reduce the case of general $S$ to say the case $S=1$?

Comment: let's say for example n=5 and S=5 .Then if 5 non-negative real numbers are choosen which sum=5. What is probability of every choosen element is less than or equal to 5/2(I.e. 2.5)

Comment: ?? I understood the question. What I'm saying is that if you solve the case $S=1$, you have solved the general case (the answer does not depend on $S$). What I'm also saying is that your question shows no effort on your part (i.e., that you should include your attempts and thoughts to your question).

Comment: Oh.. Sorry now I got it

Answer (score 3):

If you draw a point  uniformly (with respect to the $(n-1)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure) from the set $\{\,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mid x_i\ge 0,\sum x_i=S\,\}$, then by a simple scaling argument, $P(x_n>a)$ is proportional to $(S-a)^{n-1}$. From $P(x_n>0)=1$, we conclude
$$ P(x_n>a)=\left(1-\frac aS\right)^{n-1}$$ 
and in particular
$$ P(x_n>\tfrac S2)=2^{1-n}.$$
The same holds with $x_i$ in place of $x_n$. As the events $x_i>\frac S2$ are mutually exclusive, we conclude
$$ P(\forall i\colon x_i\le\tfrac S2)=1-P(\exists i\colon x_i>\tfrac S2)=1-\sum_iP(x_i>\tfrac S2)=1-n2^{1-n}$$